# NServiceBus 4.0 - Duplicate Messages

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

Does NServiceBus guarantee that a single message isn't handled by more than one thread?

I've been working under this assumption, however it seems that a single message was handled twice at the same time.

We do some non-transactional things in our handler so in our config we specify `DoNotWrapHandlersExecutionInATransactionScope`. Does this affect NServiceBus's ability to ensure that a message is only handled once? As I understand it, this just does exactly what it says and doesn't wrap with a transaction scope?

Can someone clear this up for me? 
What else could cause a duplicate message issue?

Comment: what transport are you using? MSMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your handler looks something like this:

```
public class SomeCommandHandler : IHandleMessages<SomeCommnand>
{
    public void Handle(SomeCommnand message)
    {
        // write to the database and save changes

        throw new Exception("Oh noes!");
    }
}
```

If you don't have your handler wrapped in a `TransactionScope`, I'm *guessing* (so please test on your own), that your data would be written but your message would be retried (rightfully so, because it failed).  This would give you the impression that you got the message twice.

But why are you doing anything that's non-transactional?  That kinda defeats the purpose of NServiceBus.

If you are doing things like HTTP requests or other long-running things *along with* your basic DB interaction, then you want to use a [Saga](http://docs.particular.net/NServiceBus/sagas-in-nservicebus), not a simple command handler.

Comment: So NServiceBus does guarantee that a single message isn't handled by more than one thread?

Comment: I believe it depends on which message queue you're using.  MSMQ should guarantee it because it fully supports distributed transactions: The message dequeueing and your DB interactions are all in the same transaction so if one fails, the whole message fails.  This is why Udi went with MSMQ for the default implementation.  This is also NSB's killer feature IMO.  I think it's the only service bus that supports "exactly once" delivery.

Comment: If you want more help with Sagas, just post another question and throw the link in the comments - I'll be happy to answer.

Comment: I just noticed that I didn't have .UseTransport<Msmq>() in my endpoint config. Does this matter since Msmq is the default transport?

Comment: It should default to MSMQ unless you're running it in debug mode in which case it may use in-memory queueing.  Not sure - you can check the status of the queues in the MMC snap-in.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> We do some non-transactional things in our handler so in our config we specify DoNotWrapHandlersExecutionInATransactionScope.

You can still do non-transactional things inside a handler without setting `DoNotWrapHandlersExecutionInATransactionScope`.